# After Update android support to 23.2, my icons in tabLayout cleaning after notifydatasetchenged view pager adapter

Tags: android, android-appcompat

After Update android support to 23.2, my icons in tabLayout cleaning after notifydatasetchenged view pager adapter

I set icons

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(this.tabIcons[i]);
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by cleaning?

Comment: were icons with text after text is displayed only

Comment: Did you try to use again  v23.1 and everything looks normal?

Comment: Yes, with v23.1 all right